# Self assign object its child object in constructor

Tags: java, inheritance, constructor, variable-assignment

Let's say we have:

Class `Item`:

```
public class Item {
    private Type type;

    Item(Type type) {
        this.type = type;

        if (type == Type.PISTOL || type == Type.AR || type == Type.SNIPER_RIFLE) {
            this = new Weapon(type);
        }
    }

}
```

And Class `Weapon` inherited from `Item`:

```
public class Weapon extends Item {

    Bullet.Type bulletType;
    int fireRate;

    public Weapon(Type type) {
        this.type = type;
    }
}
```

And it's called from somewhere like:

```
Item item = new Item(Item.Type.PISTOL);
```

I actually know that **`this`** is not assignable in Java but I wonder how can I work out this situation.

I want to assign `item` new `Weapon` if its type is suitable.

Comment: Have you considered using the Factory pattern?

Comment: I think It's  time  to learn  about [the factory design pattern](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to construct this way:

```
public static Item create(Type type) {
    if (type == Type.PISTOL || type == Type.AR || type == Type.SNIPER_RIFLE) {
        return new Weapon(type);
    } else {
        return new Item(type);
    }
}
```

Comment: I think that you've got a typo. `this = new Weapon` should be `return new Weapon`, shouldn't it?

Comment: @RubioRic Thanks.

Comment: Also, what bothers is the fact that, every time I create a new `Type` that represents a weapon, I would have to add some code to the `if` condition... maybe adding some method `public boolean isWeapon()` to `Type` could clean up this code a little.

Comment: I think that this method should be `static` thus it's called without any instance

Comment: @VaniaShows Better to create a factory class to handle the creation procedure.

Comment: @Turing85 I actually have Type.NONE to deal with any errors. And I provide only part of code in wich I had questions.

Comment: @Turing85 Yeah, it will make this code looks more clean.